# How can i get name from id table

Tags: html, laravel

I have a problem, I need to show my data if the status(String) is 1 in my table PO

This is my PO table

```
id | book_name            | stock |status
1  | lala land            | 10    | 0
2  | beauty and the beast | 25    | 1
3  | wawasan              | 15    | 1
```

This that i have tried

```php
..prev code
@if($po->status == '1')
@foreach($po as $p)
  <tr>
     <td> {{$p->book_name) </td>
     <td> {{$p->stok}} </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Always check your spelling and brackets. You are missing }} at the end of book_name and its stock, not stok

Answer (score 4):

The `@if` should be inside the `@foreach`

```
@foreach($po as $p)
  @if($p->status == '1')
    <tr>
       <td> {{$p->book_name}} </td>
       <td> {{$p->stok}} </td>
    </tr>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Alternatively, you could loop over the filtered collection.

```
@foreach($po->where('status', 1) as $p)
  <tr>
     <td> {{$p->book_name}} </td>
     <td> {{$p->stok}} </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if moves well with this

```
@foreach($po as $p)
  @if($p->status == '1')
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $p->book_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $p->stok }}</td>
    </tr>
  @endif    
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

for example your model name is PO,

pass this from controller function
     use App\PO;

```
 $data= PO::where('status',1)->get();
 return view('bladefilename',compact('data');
```

and then in your blade file

```
 @foreach($data as $datas)
  <tr>
     <td>{{ $datas->book_name }}</td>
     <td>{{ $datas->stok }}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps get the po that status is only true to avoid having a logic in your blade.

```
$po = PO::whereStatus(true)->get() or PO::where('status',true)->get();
```